# How can I catch an enter key ( '\n' )?

Tags: c

```
    scanf("%s", input);

    if (strlen(input) > 1) {
        errorNet();
    }

    if (input[0] == '\n') {
        errorNet();
    }

    if (input[0] == '\0') {
        errorNet();
    }
```

When I hit enter, scanf goes to the next line and continues searching for input. How can I set that if enter is hit, the function errorNet is called?

Ex. If enter/blank line is inputed, call errorNet function.

Comment: use `fgets` instead of.

Comment: Do not EVER use `scanf("%s", input)` ... this wil possibly overflow any input buffer. Use `fgets()` to read a line from `stdin`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `fgets`you specify the size of the string you are reading. `fgets` will stop reading the input when this size is reached or the user pressed `\n`. Notice that this size counts the `\0` in the end of the string.

```
char input[10];
fgets(input, 10, stdin);
printf("%s\n", input);
```

To detect if a user just pressed `\n` without writing anything, just check if the first character is a `\n`, for example:

```
if (input[0] == '\n') {
    printf("just '\\n'\n");
}
```